# How to exclude inactive users? (Spring Security)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I get all active users, but when the user logs out, it is still listed as the active user. How do I prevent a user from being listed as an active user after logging out?

I have not been able to find solutions in the documentation.

https://github.com/romanych2021/TestSession

Thanks.

**ActiveUserServiceImpl.java**

```
    @Service
    public class ActiveUserServiceImpl implements ActiveUserService{


        @Autowired
        SessionRegistry sessionRegistry;


        public List<String > getAllActiveUser(){

            List<Object> principals = sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals();
            User[] users = (User[]) principals.toArray(new User[0]);

            return Arrays.stream(users)
                    .filter(user -> !sessionRegistry.getAllSessions(user, false)
                    .isEmpty()).map(User::getUsername).collect(Collectors.toList());

        }

    }
```

**SecurityConfig.java**

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .authorizeRequests()

                    .mvcMatchers("/").permitAll()
                    .mvcMatchers("/login").anonymous()
                    .mvcMatchers("/user", "/allUser").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "USER")
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()

                    .and()
                    .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/login")

                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/")

                    .and().csrf().disable()

                    .logout()
                    .permitAll()
                    .logoutUrl("/logout")
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/")

                    .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                    .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")

                    .and().sessionManagement()
                    .maximumSessions(1)
                    .expiredUrl("/login")
                    .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry);

        }


    }
```

**HTML**

```
    <form method="post" action="/logout">
        <button type="submit">Exit</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: This helped me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64491573/how-do-i-implement-httpsessionbindinglistener-spring-security

Answer (score 1):

keep your active users map in a hashMap and remove the loooged out users from that map when day log out.In the value unbound event you can exclude inactive users.

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class ActiveUserStore {

    public HashMap<String, ActorUser> userDetails;

    public ActiveUserStore() {

        userDetails = new HashMap<>();
    }
}


@Getter
@Setter
public class LoggedUser implements HttpSessionBindingListener {


    private ActorUser sessionUser;
    private ActiveUserStore activeUserStore;

    public LoggedUser(ActorUser sessionUser, ActiveUserStore activeUserStore) {

        this.activeUserStore = activeUserStore;
        this.sessionUser = sessionUser;
    }


    @Override
    public void valueBound(HttpSessionBindingEvent event) {
        HashMap<String, ActorUser> userDetails = activeUserStore.getUserDetails();
        LoggedUser loggedUser = (LoggedUser) event.getValue();

        if (isNotNull(userDetails) && !userDetails.containsKey(loggedUser.getSessionUser().getUsername())) {
            userDetails.put(loggedUser.getSessionUser().getUsername(), loggedUser.getSessionUser());
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void valueUnbound(HttpSessionBindingEvent event) {
        LoggedUser loggedUser = (LoggedUser) event.getValue();
        HashMap<String, ActorUser> userDetails = activeUserStore.getUserDetails();

        if (isNotNull(userDetails) && isNotNull(loggedUser.getSessionUser()) &&
                userDetails.containsKey(loggedUser.getSessionUser().getUsername())) {
            userDetails.remove(loggedUser.getSessionUser().getUsername());
        }

    }
```

Comment: It helped me to solve the problem here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64491573/how-do-i-implement-httpsessionbindinglistener-spring-security

Comment: would you please explain why this is not the right solution @GENNADII

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve this problem, I needed to create only one class.

```
    package com.testsession.service;

    import org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher;
    import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;

    import javax.servlet.ServletContext;

    public class MyWebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

        @Override
        public void onStartup(ServletContext container) {
            container.addListener(new HttpSessionEventPublisher());
        }
    }
```