# How do I implement HttpSessionBindingListener? (Spring Security)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using Spring MVC without Spring Boot and without web.xml

I need to implement HttpSessionBindingListener.

I don't know how to get this to work.

I've tried many options but this doesn't want to work.

https://github.com/romanych2021/TestBindingListener

**UserActive.java**

```
    @Service
    public class UserActive implements HttpSessionBindingListener {

        Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserActive.class);

        @Override
        public void valueBound(HttpSessionBindingEvent event) {
            logger.info("Log in : {}", event.getName() );
        }

        @Override
        public void valueUnbound(HttpSessionBindingEvent event) {
            logger.info("Log out : {}", event.getName() );
        }

    }
```

**SecurityConfig.java**

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .mvcMatchers("/").permitAll()
                    .mvcMatchers("/login").anonymous()
                    .mvcMatchers("/user").hasAnyRole("ADMIN")
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                    .and().csrf().disable()
                    .logout()
                    .permitAll()
                    .logoutUrl("/logout")
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                    .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                    .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID");

        }


    }
```

**RootConfig.java**

```
    @EnableWebMvc
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    @ComponentScan({"com.testbindinglistener.security", "com.testbindinglistener.service"})
    public class RootConfig {

        @Bean
        public HttpSessionEventPublisher httpSessionEventPublisher() {
            return new HttpSessionEventPublisher();
        }

    }
```

Comment: And why do you need a `HttpSessionBindingListener`? Also if you don't use Spring Boot you need a class implementing `WebApplicationInitializer` (or extend `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer`) to register the context and add a listener. Registrering it as a bean won't work as that will only work when using Spring Boot.

Comment: Am I trying to do this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64471891/how-to-exclude-inactive-users-spring-security

Comment: Your answer helped solve my problem. Thanks.